# Remove items from ExpandableList adapter

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

I have the following problem:

I have implemented an ExpandableListView that shows me a series of records from a database. Next to each item there is a button to delete that item.

My problem is that the method that deletes the item from the ExpandableList works fine, but I want it to refresh the ExpandableList when it finishes deleting and show me the records without that item again.

This is my method from the adapter:

```
    public class BaseExpandableListViasAdapterde extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    
(...)
     public BaseExpandableListViasAdapterde(ArrayList<String> listCategoria, Map<String, ArrayList<String>> mapChild, Map<String, ArrayList<String>> mapChildNomVias, Context context) {
            this.listCategoria = listCategoria;
            this.mapChild = mapChild;
            this.mapChildNomVias = mapChildNomVias;
            this.context = context;
        }

    (...)

    @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    
            final String itemCod = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            final String itemNom = (String)getChild2(groupPosition, childPosition);
    
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.filter_child_layout_vias, null);
    
            TextView tvChildCodigoVia = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViasCod);
            TextView tvChildNombreVia = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViasnombre);
    
            ImageView buttonTrash= convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgBorrarVia);
    
            buttonTrash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    
                    String codVia = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    
                    borraViasBD(codVia); //This method delete the item in the database. Works fine.
    
                    //Try this, but don't work
                    listCategoria.remove(groupPosition);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
    
                }
            });
    
            tvChildCodigoVia.setText(itemCod);
            tvChildNombreVia.setText(itemNom);
            return convertView;
    }
    
(...)
    }
```

Any idea how to refresh the ExpandableList?
Thanks you!

Comment: Are you sure you are deleting the right list item with `listCategoria.remove(groupPosition);`? Try to call `listCategoria.remove(codVia)`

Comment: Thanks, i tried that too, but it don't seem to work. I tried deleting the Map, the ArrayList... but nothing works for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String itemCod = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    String itemNom = (String)getChild2(groupPosition, childPosition);

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.filter_child_layout_vias, null);

    TextView tvChildCodigoVia = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViasCod);
    TextView tvChildNombreVia = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViasnombre);

    ImageView buttonTrash= convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgBorrarVia);

    buttonTrash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String codVia = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            borraViasBD(codVia); //This method delete the item in the database. Works fine.

            //Try this
            ArrayList<String> listCod = mapChild.get((String)getgroup(groupPosition));
            ArrayList<String> listNom = mapChildNomVias.get((String)getgroup(groupPosition));
            listCod.remove(childPosition); // Updated
            listNom.remove(childPosition); // Updated
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    tvChildCodigoVia.setText(itemCod);
    tvChildNombreVia.setText(itemNom);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh expandable list view by implementation 3 steps below.

- After successful deletion of item form database you can refresh data
  list by removing that particular item or retrieve whole data again.
- After refreshing data list you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()`
- If `notifyDataSetChanged()` not working then you can set expandable
  list view with new data list as set beginning.